# How to inject connection string into external assembly (project) controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

My Web API is using other project for one controller. Service works fine. But I am struggling to inject connection string from main Web API project into controller in external project.

How could this be achieved?

```
public class MyExternalController : Controller
{
    private string _connStr;

    public MyExternalController(string connStr)
    {
        _connStr = connStr;
    }


    // actions here
}
```

Comment: Why are you injecting the connection string in the first place? You shouldn't use injected dependencies to build dependencies inline, you should inject the service configured already

Comment: You can only inject Services that have been registered. You should be injecting a `DbContext` instead.

Comment: Reference [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others said in the comments, for something like a controller, you should be injecting something concrete like a `DbContext`, not a connection string. However, for future reference your issue here is injecting a string. There's no way to register something in the DI container to satisfy a dependency like that. Instead, you should inject your configuration or a strongly-typed configuration class.

Injecting `IConfigurationRoot` is a bit of an anti-pattern, but for something like a connection string, it's fine:

```
public MyExternalController(IConfigurationRoot config)
{
    _connStr = config.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
}
```

For everything else, though, you should use strongly-typed configuration classes.

```
public class FooConfig
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Configure<FooConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("Foo"));
```

Which of course would correspond with some bit of config like:

```
{
    "Foo": {
        "Bar": "Baz"
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, for example:

```
public MyExternalController(IOptionsSnapshot<FooConfig> fooConfig)
{
    _fooConfig = fooConfig.Value;
}
```